# Retrieve interface number in Windows driver

Tags: windows, usb, driver, msdn

In my INF file I write following line to load interface number `01` from my composite USB device:

```
%DeviceName%=Device_Install, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX&MI_01
```

Now how do I retrieve this interface number in my driver? I can access the device instace ID by [IWDFDevice::RetrieveDeviceInstanceId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558837(v=vs.85).aspx) which would give me the interface number packed in a string:

```
 "USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX&MI_01\6&336AF67A&0&0002"
```

I could extract it from this string but there must be a more elegant way?